# Elementary Borsuk-Ulam Proof Help

Tags: general-topology

I'm working through "Elementary proof of Borsuk-Ulam Theorem" found [here](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~scepin/elem-proof-reduct.pdf).

> Lemma 2: If there exists a continuous mapping of $f: \mathbb S^n \to \mathbb R^n$, which
>    does not identify any pair of antipodes, then there exists an odd
>    continuous mapping $g: \mathbb S^n \to \mathbb S^{n-1}$. Explicit formula for such a mapping $g(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{|f(x)-f(-x)|}$.

**What does "identify" mean rigorously?**

Comment: Seems that it means the following: if $a,b\in\mathbb S^n$ are antipodes then $f(a)\neq f(b)$.

Answer (score 3):

In this case "to identify" means "to map to the same point". Hence a mapping $f:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ does not identify any pair of antipodes if and only if $f(x)\neq f(-x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{S}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

It means $f(x)=f(-x)$ and that would cause denominator of $g$ being zero.